# Are vectors linearly independent iff they form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to show that if a set of vectors form a basis, they must necessarily be linearly independent, but is the converse true, and how would you show it?

Comment: @AhmedHussein How would you prove that?

Comment: The vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are linearly independent but are not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What definition of basis are you working with? If it's the same as Wikipedia's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) then you just need to show that they span.

Comment: @J.Gudal that was a mistake. I did not pay attention to a detail. But note that if the vector space is finite dimensional (say of dimension $n$), then any collection of $n$ linearly independent vectors is a basis. You can find a proof in many places online.

Comment: @EliRose Sorry I'm just a bit confused as my textbook seems to be using a different definition. My one seems to be along the lines of "A subset of a vector space V such that any vector in V can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of these vectors". This definition doesn't assume linear independence does it?

Comment: @AndréNicolas So if a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space, then these form a basis?

Comment: Yes, for $n$ finite. As to your comment before that, the definition you gave does not mention linear independence, but one can prove they are linearly independent from the can be expressed **uniquely** part.

Comment: I didn't see the comments initially. I added a proof of the equivalence of your definitions in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an extension to the comments, any subset of linearly independent vectors is itself linearly independent, however if you remove a vector from any linearly independent set, it will no longer be in the span of that set. So to get a set of linearly independent vectors that is **not** a basis, just remove a vector from *any* basis for the specific vector space.

If however you have $n$ linearly independent vectors and your vector space is $n$-dimensional, then they form a basis.

*Proof*: Suppose there are $n$ linearly independent vectors and the vector space is $n$ dimensional. If you have another vector $r$, then the $n$ linearly independent vectors and $r$ are linearly dependent, so we can write $r$ as a linear combination of the original $n$ vectors i.e. they form a basis.

To your question in the comments:suppose that the dimension of our vector space is $n$. Then there exists basis vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ (else the dimension of the vector space would not be $n$). Consider $v_{n+1}$ which is different to all the vectors $v_1,...v_n$ in the basis. Then $v_{n+1} = a_1 v_1+...+a_n v_n$ since $v_1,...v_n$ form a basis (i.e. we can write any other vector in the vector space  as a linear combination of these vectors). This means exactly that $v_{n+1}$ is linearly dependent to $v_1,...v_n$.

Now interchange $v_{n+1}$ with $r$ and "*$n$ linearly independent vectors*" with $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Can you prove the last statement please?

Comment: "...If you have another vector $r$ then the $n$ linearly independent vectors and $r$ are linearly dependent..." Why is this true?

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549126/show-that-any-n1-vectors-in-a-n-dimensional-vector-space-forms-a-linearly-d

Comment: What I got from those answers is that "its just how things are". I'm just really confused now, as there seem to be different definitions of a basis being used. Nm I'll read over some other sources. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you read the edited link? The accepted answer shows that any $n+1$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional vector space are linearly dependent. What is confusing you there?

Comment: See updated answer, I have tried to explain it here.

Comment: Ok so if we begin with a vector space $V$ which has dimension $n$ ($n$ is finite), and we have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$. We want to show that from these vectors, we can form any other vector in $V$ by linearly combining them. The apparent "proof" for this is that  $V$ has dimension $n$. What I was looking for was a proof that follows the structure: "for any other vector $v$ in the vector space we can write "..." hence $v$ is a linear combination of these vectors". If none of this made sense, please ignore it.

Comment: Thanks you answered my question. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a subset forms a basis if it is linearly independent AND spans the space. If you are working with finite dimensional vector spaces, then span is very easy to describe, namely, it is just all linear combinations of the vectors. To read more, including the general definition, you can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span

You can alternatively define it, in the finite dimensional case, as

> A subset such that every vector can uniquely be written as a linear combination.

Say the vector space is $V$ and the subset is $S = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$
Suppose the former definition. Then $\forall v \in V$, $v$ is expressible as some linear combination, although not necessarily unique. Let's suppose it had two such linear combinations, $v = \sum c_i v_i = \sum d_i v_i $ Now subtract the two to get $\sum (c_i - d_i ) v_i = 0$. By linear independence then, $c_i - d_i = 0$.

Conversely, suppose every vector can uniquely be written as a linear combination. Then span is satisfied so it remains to check independence. Suppose $\sum c_i v_i = 0 \in V$. Note that the key here is that $0$ is an element of the vector space, namely the zero vector. By assumption, zero has a unique expression as a linear combination in terms of $S$, namely $0 = \sum 0 \cdot v_i$. Thus by unicity, $c_i = 0$ $\forall i$, thus satisfying independence.