# Show that in an n-dimensional vector space, any collection of m vectors, where m>n, must be linearly dependent

Tags: vector-spaces

I only found [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549126/show-that-any-n1-vectors-in-a-n-dimensional-vector-space-forms-a-linearly-d) question related to this one. I didn't love the answers provided so I want to provide my own and get some feedback.

Theorem:

In an n-dimensional vector space, any collection of m vectors, where m>n, must be linearly dependent.

Proof:

Define our vector space to be n-dimensional. Then each coordinate the space is specified by exactly by a tuple of n elements. Define a collection of m vectors where m > n. Label this collection of vectors as {$v_1,v_2, \dots, v_m$}. Consider the first $n$ vectors {$v_1,\dots,v_n$}.

Case 1:
Assume any of the vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. We're done. (Adding more vectors won't eliminate the linear dependency of these vectors)

Case 2:
Assume all n of the vectors are linearly independent. Remember that these vectors live in n-dimensional space. Add another vector {$v_{n+1}$}. We now show that $v_{n+1}$ is equal to some combination of the other vectors $v_{n+1}$. Assume, by contradiction, that $v_{n+1}$ is not a linear combination of $v_1, \dots, v_n$. Then there is some spot in the n-dimensional space that $v_1, \dots, v_n$ can't reach. Which is a contradiction.

That's what I'm thinking, is there a good way to tighten up the argument or is this okay?

Comment: it depends on your definition of n-dimensional space

Comment: You don't need to consider "Case 1"; it amounts to saying "if they're linearly dependent then they're linearly dependent" which is tautologically true and not of any use. In Case 2 you're assuming that if $n$ vectors in $V$ are linearly independent then they span, which depending on where you're at in your course you may need to prove, or at least cite explicitly. You also haven't proven anything about the case where you can't find $n$ vectors among $\{ v_1, \dots v_m \}$ which are linearly independent.

Comment: I’d you can’t find n vectors that are linearly dependent then you’re done before you started. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m$ vectors are independent, then $\rm{dim}V\ge m \gt n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Love it. If the question shows up on the test I’ll just write this haha

Comment: Well, you have got to start somewhere.  Otherwise you are reduced to writing a book called _Dimension Theory_, which already exists (and is very good).

Comment: this? https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-22232-1

Comment: No.  I was referring to Witold Hurewitz's classic.  Didn't realize, but should have, that there was another.

Comment: Spelling: Hurewicz